3-Hitting-Set with 3-Approximation
The 3-Hitting-Set Problem is defined as a set $F$ of 3-element subsets of a ground set $U$ with size $|U| = n$, and the goal is to find the smallest subset $S \subseteq U$ such that $S$ has a non-empty intersection with each set in $F$, i.e., for each $f \in F$, it holds that $f \cap S \ne \emptyset$.
Now it is asked to provide a factor-3 approximation algorithm that runs in polynomial time and prove the correctness of the approximation factor.
Greedy-Algorithm

Let $R = F$.
WHILE $R \ne \emptyset$:
Choose the element that hits the most sets in $R$ and remove all the sets hit from $R$.
Return chosen elements.

How can we show, that the solution of this algorithm is maximum three times larger than the optimal solution?

I don't think the greedy algorithm is a factor-3 approximation algorithm here. But there is a short solution generalizing the factor-2 approximation algorithm for vertex cover. Are you familiar with that algorithm?

The following example shows that your greedy approach is not a $3$-approximation scheme.
Let $U = \{\,u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_{40}, v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_{19}, w_0, w_1, \ldots, w_{19}, x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_{379}\,\}$. Let's define additional sequences
$$(d_i)_{i = 0}^{40} = 20, 19, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 14, 13, 12, 12, 11, 10, 10, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,$$
and $(k_i)_{i = 0}^{40} = \sum_{j < i}d_j$.
To form $F$ let's do the following. For every $i = 0, 1, \ldots, 19$ add set $\{\,v_i, w_i, x_i\,\}$ to $F$. Then for every $i = 0, 1, \ldots, 40$ and for every $j = 0, 1, \ldots, d_i - 1$ add set $\{\,u_i, v_{(k_i + j) \bmod 20}, x_{20 + k_i + j}\,\}$ to $F$.
The optimal solution for this instance is $S = \{\,v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_{19}\,\}$, while your greedy approach will return $\{u_0, u_1, \ldots, u_{40}, y_0, y_1, \ldots, y_{19}\}$, where $y_i \in \{\,v_i, w_i, x_i\,\}$.
The idea of this example is that each $v_i$ should belong up to $19$ sets in $F$. And we add $u_i$ one by one so that it will belong to greater number of remaining sets in $F$ than any $v_j$, however we uniformly select $v_j$ to share set with $u_i$. That's why the number of subsets containing $u_i$ may decrease when $i$ increases.
After getting initial set $F$ every $v_i$ belongs to exactly $19$ sets in $F$. At the same time $u_0$ belongs to $20$ sets in $F$, therefore it will be taken first. Then $v_i$ belongs to exactly $18$ remaining sets in $F$, while $u_1$ and $u_2$ belong to $19$ remaining sets each and don't share any set (like any other pair of $(u_{i_1}, u_{i_2})$). So they will be added to the resulting set. And so on. You may check that at every moment there is $u_i$ which belongs to strictly greater number of remaining sets in $F$ than any of $v_j$. Taking this $u_i$ we decrease the number of remaining sets containing some of $v_j$ giving chance to other $u_t$ to be selected.
